Can I think of probability convolution as defining a C*-multiplication on a dual space?
This question may not be well-phrased.
A probability measure is a linear functional, and is actually a state on $C_0(X)$ for a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ with a suitable sigma-algebra. I'm wondering,

when thinking of convolutions of probability measures, should I think of them as a multiplication on dual space $C_0(X)^*$?

But this way of thinking seems strange, because I don't think I've ever heard of "multiplying a linear functional with another linear functional and producing a third linear functional". Although, I do know the concept of a predual, and the fact that Hilbert space compact operators is the predual of trace-class operators. But these are in a totally different contexts. (Apology if I'm mixing unrelated things up. I'm self-learning without too much guidance.) Thanks in advance.

First, in order to define convolution, you need $X$ to have a group structure, instead of just being a locally compact Hausdorff space. Once you assume $X$ is a locally compact group, however, you do have that convolution defines a multiplication on $C_0(X)^\ast$. This happens because the group structure on $X$ defines a co-multiplication $\Delta: C_0(X) \to M(C_0(X) \otimes C_0(X)) = C_b(X \times X)$ by,
$$\Delta(f)(x, y) = f(xy)$$
Generally speaking, co-multiplication dualizes to multiplication on the dual space, so naturally, we have a multiplication $\ast: C_0(X)^\ast \times C_0(X)^\ast \to C_0(X)^\ast$ given by,
$$\varphi \ast \psi(f) = (\varphi \otimes \psi)(\Delta(f))$$
which is exactly the convolution product.
While multiplying linear functionals may sound strange, if you think about examples, it’s actually all quite standard objects. If $X$ is a discrete group, say, the dual space is just $\ell^1(X)$ and the convolution product simply defines the group algebra. More generally, if you only consider those measures that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Haar measure, the convolution product defines the group algebra $L^1(X)$. So, for any locally compact group, you always have one algebra with commutative multiplication and possibly non-co-commutative co-multiplication, namely $C_0(X)$, $C_b(X)$, or $L^\infty(X)$. Dually, you always have another algebra with possibly non-commutative multiplication and a commutative co-multiplication, namely various group algebras such as $\mathbb{C}[X]$, $C^\ast_r(X)$, $C^\ast(X)$, $W^\ast(X)$, $C_0(X)^\ast$, etc. (Though the co-multiplication may not be well-defined for $L^1(X)$.) This is the non-commutative version of Pontryagin duality, and, in a sense, this observation is what makes the concept of quantum groups possible.
